# Conflict between sql server 2008 r2 and 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have both SQL Server 2008 r2 and SQL Server 2012 installed, but when I open SQL Server 2008 r2 management studio and enter by (localhost), it's version seems to be 11.0.2218 which is for sql server 2012 management studio, so I can't access or create older tables.
Is there any way to change SQL Server management studio?

Comment: You don't log into the correct server. Your 2012 is probably the Default instance, and your 2008 is a named instance installation. I also have 2008 and 2012 installed, and I don't have that bevahiour. Why don't you use 2012 Management Studio ?

Comment: Thank you, I had work good before, But I don't know what happened to it! I can't find any instance name for 2008

Answer (score 0):

Open your SQL Server Configuration Manager, Under SQL Server Network Configuration you will find `Protocols for` and all the instances that is installed will be there. `MSSQLSERVER` is the default instance. Find your instance name there.

There other option is to run `regedit` Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server` You will find keys like.

`MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER` and
`MSSQL11.SQLEXPRESS`

Yours will be different though.

That will show you the SQL Server version and instance. Mine show MSSQL10.5 which is 2008 R2 as MSSQLSERVER which is the default instance, and MSSQL11  as SQLEXPRESS which is my named instance for 2012