# html display texts and shapes on picture hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there any way that when I hover a picture, it displays red lines and rectangles and names.
How can I do that with HTML & CSS? and it would be appreciated that show me a link that teaches me how to make it responsive.

[image: picture 1: before hover]

[image: picture 2: on hover]

Comment: You can't just ask people to write code for you. This question does not regard a specific problem and is way too broad.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I don't want code! I just need to know if there is any specific technique to do that.

Comment: It's not your [first](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38588911/some-images-does-not-show-in-firefox) [broad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28957798/use-next-and-previous-button-for-long-column-chart) [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101150/conflict-between-sql-server-2008-r2-and-2012) - Please visit the help center and [learn how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fiddle showing how to do the hover effect you asked about: https://jsfiddle.net/Darin_Cardin/0b1fynuo/16/

This code is the key:

```
$(".pantrollover").hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.rollovertop').fadeOut("fast");

},function(){   
    $(this).find('.rollovertop').fadeIn("fast");
});
```

Answer (score -1):

show/hide on hover child element which has position absolute. If you want to your div to have specific shape of shown people use svg clipping mask.